# Stream data with Node.js HTTP API or Websockets?

Tags: node.js, streaming, websocket

With node.js i can stream data to the client with its HTTP API. But when do I want to use HTTP to stream data and when do i want to use node.js sockets.io to do streaming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use Socket.IO universally because it cleverly selects the most appropriate transport method for performing IO based on what's available to the browser.